# How do I test my browser timezone dependent application againts different timezones?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm making a Javascript web application that depends on user's browser time zone.

For example, whenever I check the UTC offset, I find it to be +5.5 only.

How do I test if it works in other time zones as well? I specially want to see how it works with US time zones.

I use Firefox mostly. Is there any configuration setting I can edit? I tried changing my system time zone, but it didn't work.

Comment: On Firefox 45.0.1 + Windows 7, changing system timezone and refreshing works (at http://everytimezone.com/ for example).

Comment: @S.Kirby, A refresh will work.

Answer (score 17):

You need to restart your browser after you change your system's timezone. Firefox keeps the original timezone, I believe, and Chrome thinks you are in UTC if you do not restart.

Comment: ...or simply open another instance of FF or Chrome if (like me) you're a tab hoarder :-)

Comment: In Chrome at least, I don't need to restart the browser. Simply close the tab and then reopen it.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu, simple (F5) refresh worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: Is there anything we can do with Developer Tools on Chrome to spoof System Timezone?

Comment: @RaviDhoriya , **Yes** definitely. Is there a way to set **arbitrary** timezones? For example **+15:00** (which doesn't exist since [14 is max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00)) and "subdecimals" like **+08:12:04.3384**. This would be useful to do "ease testing".

Answer (score 8):

In this regard, I've used this script on OS X: [fresh-chrome-with-custom-tz.sh](https://gist.github.com/prasadsilva/225fd0394a51e52bf62f)

The script starts an instance of Chrome with its own environment. To configure it to use a specific timezone, edit this in the script:

```sh
# Change this to the spoof a different timezone. Helpful for testing timezone specific client facing content.
export TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```

It relies on the TZ environment variable.
Works like a charm!

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Made my life a lot easier!